# Netty websocket client example with a given PKCS12

Tags: java, websocket, netty, pkcs#12

I have the **client.p12** file and **MyPassword**, I am trying to establish the websocket connection using [Netty code available over here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/client/WebSocketClientHandler.java). Currently I have the working example in OkHttpClient. But I am having a hard time to map that into netty.

My server gave me this domain to connect to "https://api.server.com"

In OkHttpClient the following code works

```java
    OkHttpClient client = getClient(info);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://api.server.com" + "/messaging").build();
    WebSocket webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
```

Here the getClient code is following:

```java
    public static OkHttpClient getClient(ConnectionInfo info) {

      KeyStore appKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      appKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream("client.p12"), "MyPassword".toCharArray());
      KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      keyManagerFactory.init(appKeyStore, info.getPassword().toCharArray());

      TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
      TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

      if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
              "Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
      }

      X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {trustManager}, null);
      context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

      OkHttpClient.Builder builder =
        new OkHttpClient.Builder().sslSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory(), trustManager);

      builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);

      return builder.build();
  }
```

Now that code above works fine, I am trying to implement this in Netty. So looking at example code it only accepts the protocols `ws` and `wss`. While in the above example The HTTPS requests Upgraded to WebSocket using the appropriate headers. So my understanding is that If I provide the domain name as "wss:////api.server.com/messaging" Then it will first establish the https connection and then upgrade it to WebSocket.

Now I am not sure how to set the certificate and password.

```java
    // I have created a keyStore as following
    KeyStore keyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("client.p12"));
    try {
      keyStore.load(instream, "MyPassword".toCharArray());
    } finally {
      instream.close();
    }

    final boolean ssl = "wss".equalsIgnoreCase(scheme);
    final SslContext sslCtx;
    if (ssl) {
     // How to specify the above keystore with this client?
      sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
        .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
    } else {
      sslCtx = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SSlContextBuilder` has a method that takes a `KeyManagerFactory`:

```
SslContextBuilder.forClient()
    .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
    .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
    .build();
```